# Count word frequency in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, frequency, word-frequency

I am trying to write a code to count the frequency of word occurrences in a document containing about 10000 files, but instead of getting the overall frequency, I get the word count of the last file, since it will overwrite the previous iteration. My code so far is:

```
import csv
import glob
import re


def main():
    file_list = glob.glob(TARGET_FILES)
    for file in file_list:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
             doc = f_in.read()

 def get_data(doc):    

     vdictionary = {}
     w = csv.writer(open("output1.csv", "w",newline=''))
     tokens = re.findall('\w+', doc)  
     for token in tokens:
        if token not in vdictionary:
             vdictionary[token] = 1
        else:
             vdictionary[token] += 1
     for key, val in vdictionary.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
```

Comment: Your code defines two functions that are never called. They don't even call each other. It's hard to tell what your code is supposed to do when it's such an incomplete program like this. But I notice that the name of the output file is hard-coded ("output1.csv"). You can either choose a different file name in each iteration, or open the file in append mode and write all the results into the same file. Anyway, we need a [mcve]. We can't debug code that doesn't work without any information about what the expected result is.

Comment: It seems that it is true that you overwrite with each iteration (based on what is provided). I'd suggest looking into storing your information into a `list` so that you won't overwrite. It also seems that you might not have included all the code. (The `get_data` 
and `main` functions never get called)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you empty the csv file with every iteration. What happens if you use:

```
w = csv.writer(open("output1.csv", "a",newline=''))
```

instead of

```
w = csv.writer(open("output1.csv", "w",newline=''))
```

? I suspect you'll get a count for each file. If that is the case, you should make one dictionary, update that for each file and only at the end write it to the csv file.

You can get one dictionary like this:

```
 def get_data(doc, vdictionary):
     tokens = re.findall('\w+', doc)  
     for token in tokens:
         if token not in vdictionary:
             vdictionary[token] = 1
         else:
             vdictionary[token] += 1
     return vdictionary

 def main():
     files = {get your files}
     vdictionary = {}
     for file in files:
           vdictionary = get_data(file, vdictionary)
     w = csv.writer(open("output1.csv", "w",newline=''))
     for key, val in vdictionary.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
```

Comment: Appending doesn't work because I think he wants counts of a word in all files. If a word appears in multiple files it will have separate entries if he appends.

Comment: @WilliamGodel You're right, thanks. It would still be useful for a quick test to see if this is indeed what causes the error. I added a bit explaining how to continue from there.

Comment: Np. You're right that if the append works it identifies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that every time you call get_data, you're rewriting the csv with only the counts from that file (I think). Instead, perhaps you could create a dictionary, then go through and do the counts of each word in each file for all files, then output to `w.writerow([key, val])`.

Essentially, do not output to the csv every time you go through a file. Go through all the files, updating one master dictionary, then output to a csv.